# setting image position fixed inside a textbox in asp.net C# using Css properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a textbox where I want to insert an image inside it using css class properties in asp.net C# in the source code of asp.net page. My prob is that when the user types the text continuosly my image shifts.I want my image position fixed. I have tried many options such as image position fixed properties in css but no solution. I am pasting my code below:

```
<head runat ="server">

<style type="text/css">

    .search
    {
        background: url('index.jpg') no-repeat;
        padding-left: 25px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="search" Width="127px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am using Internet Explorer for my output. Does this browser does not support my coding?

Comment: Add a div , set index.jpg on proper place , now place textbox on that div and set outline and border to 0px of textbox using css !

Comment: my textbox is already inside a div. I will paste u the coding again

<head runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
        .search
        {
            background: url('index.jpg') no-repeat;
            padding-left: 25px;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
        }
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="search" Width="127px"></asp:TextBox>
<div>
Already a div is created in our page form in asp.net.If u mean something else pls specify exactly where to add a div